# Firebase push notifications callback doesn't work when app is terminated

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, remote-notifications

So I updated the [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/example) and I had to change my code because `FirebaseMessagin.configure()` is deprecated and now when I receive the notification and click on the notification it doesn't open another screen.

This is how I implemented the notifications:

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}
const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'high_importance_channel', // id
  'High Importance Notifications', // title
  'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
  importance: Importance.high,
);

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'e-Rădăuți',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (_) => MenuScreen(),
        '/events': (BuildContext context) => EventsScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
class MenuScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                channel.description,
                icon: 'launch_background',
              ),
            ));
      }
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      debugPrint('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
      
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/events');
    });
  }
}
```

But `.onMessageOpenedApp` isn't called when I click on the notification because I don't get that `debugPrint` message in my console (VSCode) and I get the following errors:

```
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver( 4799): broadcast received for message
W/civic.e_radaut( 4799): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(I)Z (greylist,test-api, reflection, allowed)
W/civic.e_radaut( 4799): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(ILjava/lang/String;)Z (greylist,test-api, reflection, allowed)
W/civic.e_radaut( 4799): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->get(I)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/civic.e_radaut( 4799): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->getName(I)Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/FirebaseMessaging( 4799): Notification Channel set in AndroidManifest.xml has not been created by the app. Default value will be used.
I/flutter ( 4799): Handling a background message 0:1617783965733220%2ebdcc762ebdcc76
```

I sent my notification from the firebase with the `click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK` and in my manifest I've added

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

My `firebase_messaging` version is `^8.0.0-dev.15`

So I don't know what I've missed or why it's not working. If you need more details please feel free to ask.

Comment: hi, i have the same problem with firebasemessaging ^9.1.3, FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen is not triggered  when notificacion is tapped and app is on foreground. did you found any solution?

Comment: @ALEXANDERLOZANO sorry for the late reply.. I think that if the app is in the foreground you should use `.onMessage.listen' because the app is already opened and in foreground so you actually don't open the app so `FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen` is not called but instead is called `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen`. I'm not sure if this will work because I didn't implement an call back when the app is in the foreground. If you didn't find a solution message me and I'll try to implement in my code and see if it will work

Comment: thank you for your answer, i use:
 FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print("new message");
    });

with not luck. notification arrive but listen is not triggered

Comment: I added a `debugPrint();` in `.onMessage` and it's triggered if the app is in foreground but not when I click on it, it's triggered when I receive the notification. If I find a solution I'll tell you

Comment: @ALEXANDERLOZANO So it seems that you have to add local push notifications and work with that to make the callback when the app is in foreground.. I'll make a demo app tomorrow.. it's 1:40 AM :(

Comment: @ALEXANDERLOZANO here is the demo app that I created https://github.com/SK1n/flutter_notifications_example . Hope it helps

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, still not luck, as i need firebase_messaging  firebasemessaging ^9.1.3, the notification click is not working in foreground,  but, let me invite you a cup of coffee

Comment: Yeah sure, maybe I can help you. I mean I can't see your code so it is kind of hard to help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I resolved this by using the `.getInitialMessage()` function (This is the callback if the app is terminated.
My notifications worked when the app was on background but not terminated.

To resolve this I just added this to my code:

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance
    .getInitialMessage()
    .then((RemoteMessage message) {
  if (message != null) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, message.data['view']);
  }
});
```

I've made a working demo [here](https://github.com/SK1n/flutter_notifications_example)

Comment: Thank you! I tried your code and it works.

Comment: Finally! Thanks! <3

Comment: How to make Android works on terminated firebase notifications?

Answer (score 1):

It should work when the app is in the background, but when it is terminated you should use `getInitialMessage`.

> `onMessageOpenedApp`: A Stream event will be sent if the app has opened from a background state (not terminated).
>
> If your app is opened via a notification whilst the app is terminated, see [`getInitialMessage`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/8.0.0-dev.15/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/getInitialMessage.html).

Check out the example: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/example/lib/main.dart#L116

Answer (score 1):

if you want go to any page or  lunch link when click notification before app started then you must use

> `getInitialMessage()`

example:

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance
    .getInitialMessage()
    .then((RemoteMessage message) {
  if (message != null) {

   //to do your operation
   launch('https://google.com');

  }
});
```