# Azure NotificationHub Android: onPushNotificationReceived not getting called when Android App is in Background/Terminated State

Tags: android, azure, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

When Android App is in **Foreground** State, **onPushNotificationReceived** listener is getting invoked having the notification data. When in **Background** or **Terminated** State, Notification does get received but onPushNotificationReceived listener is not getting invoked neither automatically nor when I tap on the notification. I'm sending the push from Azure Portal.

{
"notification":{
"title":"Notification Hub Test Notification",
"body":"This is a sample notification delivered by Azure Notification Hubs."
},
"data":{
"property1":"value1",
"property2":53
},
"priority": "high"
}

I'm following Tutorial: Send push notifications to Android devices using Firebase SDK version 1.0.0-preview1 (Current SDK) tutorial.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/android-sdk

**Android OS: 11**

Is there something else which i need to do apart from the mentioned steps in the above link?

[image: NotificationListener]

[image: AndroidManifest]

[image: MainActivity]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your app is in the background or closed then a notification message is shown in the notification center, and any **data from that message is passed to the intent** that is launched as a result of the user tapping on the notification.

When the intent is launched you can use the `getIntent().getExtras();`

`onMessageReceived` is provided for most message types, which follows

- **Notification messages delivered when your app is in the background**. The notification is delivered to the device’s system
  tray. A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by
  default.
- **Messages with both notification and data payload, when received in the background**. The notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

Refer [Handling response](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) & [Push notification in android](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-push-notification-in-android-using-firebase-cloud-messaging/) to implement in your project.

You can use the **.getInitialMessage()**  on **FirebaseMessaging** instance

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance
    .getInitialMessage()
    .then((RemoteMessage message) {
        if (message != null) {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, message.data['view']);
    }
});
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67346514/15997690)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that, when the app is in background, the notification is received, but not by the **onPushNotificationReceived** listener.
Looking at the logcat in Android Studio, I see a message after sending the push notification.
Thus, I implemented a NotificationListener with a filter on the title of the notification to which I want to react in my app. The code within the filter is implemented in a class in order to reuse it to handle the foreground/background cases.

I think this is a workaround, the problem I'm encountering is that, after the Android device has display off for more than about 15 minutes (it enters dooze mode), then notifications are not received anymore.

I post below the snippet of my NotificationListener

```
public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {
    public NotificationService()
    {
        super();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted (StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        if(sbn != null && sbn.getNotification() != null && sbn.getNotification().extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE) != null)
        {
            String title = sbn.getNotification().extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE).toString();
            if(title.equals("alert"){
                // ** Code to react to notification 
            }

        }
    }

}
```